# DbContext not working from Package Manager Console

Tags: nuget-package, dbcontext, t4scaffolding

I am unable to **Scaffold-DbContext** from Package Manager Console. I have to do this instead **"dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold"**

Is there anything I can do to fix this on my PC?